# Converting data to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, matching, game-theory

I'm new to R and to programming in general. I have this data: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs8O9.png) 
[image]

I have 12 'IDs' (research subjects), numbered 1-12. The 'types' column tells the 'type' of each ID. For example, the first 5 numbers of the 'types' column refer to the 'types' of first 5 IDs, i.e. 'types' of first 5 IDs are 3,3,2,1,1 respectively.

The 'pairs' column describes how IDs are paired together. For example, 6 is paired with 9; 4 is paired with 7; 1 is paired with 11 and so on.

So what I need help with is that I want to create three columns using this data.

**first column:** lists the ID (1-12) 
**second column:** returns the ID of the *pair* (like 1 was paired with 11, so second column should say 11 for ID 1)
**third column:** tells the *'type'* of the pair (so 'type' of 11 is 3. third column should display that.

Here's a visualization of the desired output format: [output format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy1BV.png) 
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with some clever indexing.  I entered the raw data as a vector for types, and a list of vectors for pairs:

```
# Enter the raw data
type <- c(3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1)
pairs <- list(c(6, 9), c(4, 7), c(1, 11), c(3, 10), c(2, 12), c(5, 8))
```

From this, you can create the first two columns of the desired output by stacking all of the pairs once in their original order, and then again in the reverse order.  (I reversed each pair by using `lapply(pairs, rev)`, which applies the `rev` command to each pair in the list.)

```
# Create a 12 x 2 matrix of the pairs
pairs.mat <- do.call(rbind, c(pairs, lapply(pairs, rev)))
pairs.mat
#       [,1] [,2]
#  [1,]    6    9
#  [2,]    4    7
#  [3,]    1   11
#  [4,]    3   10
#  [5,]    2   12
#  [6,]    5    8
#  [7,]    9    6
#  [8,]    7    4
#  [9,]   11    1
# [10,]   10    3
# [11,]   12    2
# [12,]    8    5
```

For cleanliness of results, I converted this into a `data.frame`:

```
# Convert to data frame
colnames(pairs.mat) <- c("id", "match")
df <- as.data.frame(pairs.mat)
```

Finally, we can get the type_match column by taking type in the order of the match column from the `data.frame` we just created.

```
# Add in the type_match column
df$type_match <- type[df$match]

# Print results in order
df[order(df$id), ]
#    id match type_match
# 3   1    11          3
# 5   2    12          1
# 4   3    10          1
# 2   4     7          2
# 6   5     8          3
# 1   6     9          1
# 8   7     4          1
# 12  8     5          1
# 7   9     6          1
# 10 10     3          2
# 9  11     1          3
# 11 12     2          3
```

And that should give you the desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the help! 
Just one more thing: For the 'pairs' list in the beginning, is there a way to directly read those pairings off of the .csv file? The reason I'm asking for that is I only gave the picture of one round of pairing; there are several more. So, I was hoping to write a function that reads the pairing sequence from a .csv file for each round and then proceeds with the code you provided.
Once again, thanks for the help!

Comment: @AkhtarShah Probably, but what does the CSV look like?

Comment: [dropbox link to csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7icth1rmv9801i3/config_custom_short_72.csv?dl=0)
Don't know how to share that in the comments; therefore, the link.

Comment: That's much trickier, because you have several variables per line of the CSV.  Do the data have to be in that format, or is there another way to output them?